# Injecting datasource in grails 3 ignores additional properties set in application.groovy

Tags: grails, grails3

I'm using grails 3.3.9 and I have a datasource in application.groovy defined as:

```
    username = ...
    password = ...
    ...
    properties {
      ...
      maxActive=16 
      testOnBorrow=true
      testWhileIdle=true
      ...
   }
```

I want to inject the datasource in a service so I inject it by defining:

```
class MyService {
   def dataSource
  
    def myMethod() {
       def sql = new Sql(dataSource)
    ...
    }
}
```

The problem is that the properties set in application.groovy are ignored and the defaults are used: i.e. maxActive=10, testOnBorrow=false, testWhileIdle=false.

I wonder how can I inject the datasource and keep the properties defined in application.groovy...

**Later edit**

It looks like the cause of this issue was actually the grails hibernate-filter-plugin. Without it the datasource looks good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would need to see the full datasource. Might be a problem further up. Also, if you are defining the datasource in your yaml, it will overwrite your application.groovy properties (I believe)

Comment: Thanks! You are right, the hibernate-filter-plugin was the cause of this issue.